# Select em registros de tabela com relação MxN

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Olá, eu tenho no meu banco uma tabela tb_usuario **(id INT, nome VARCHAR, flag_ativo INT)** e uma tabela **tb_regional(id INT, nome VARCHAR,login VARCHAR, senha VARCHAR)**. Do relacionamento entre as duas surge a tabela **tb_regional_usuario(tb_regional_id INT, tb_usuario_id INT)**. Pois bem, eu gostaria de saber como montar uma query que onde eu informe o id do usuário e o banco me retorne as regionais para as quais ele tem permissão de acesso. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso sua tabela esta estruturada assim:

```
|-----tb_usuario-------|
|id - nome - flag_ativo|
|----------------------|

|--------tb_regional------|
|id - nome - login - senha|
|-------------------------|

|------tb_regional_usuario-----|
|tb_regional_id - tb_usuario_id|
|------------------------------|
```

Para trazer os dados desejados você pode utilizar `inner join`.
Ficaria assim:

```
select *
from tb_usuario
inner join tb_regional_usuario on (tb_usuario.id = tb_regional_usuario.tb_usuario_id)
inner join tb_regional on (tb_regional_usuario.tb_regional_id = tb_regional.id)
where tb_usuario.id = 5; //TROQUE O ID PELO DESEJADO
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim, era exatamente isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um `INNER JOIN` entre as três tabelas:

```
SELECT r.id, r.nome
FROM tb_usuario u
INNER JOIN tb_regional_usuario ru ON ru.tb_usuario_id = u.id
INNER JOIN rb_regional r ON r.id = ru.tb_regional_id
WHERE u.id = :tb_usuario_id
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante. Obrigado pelo retorno.